# Is "And this X?" a common English expression?

Tags: expressions, idioms

In Spanish we say, "And this X?" as a short form for "And who is X?" Example:

> When I entered the room with Billy, Tom looked up and said, "And this high school brat?"

Is this also a common expression in English? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Comment: The closest I can think of is "...and this would be. . . ?" which is used if someone you know brings along someone you don't know. It means, roughly, "Please introduce that guy."  But you probably wouldn't use it with a pre-judging pejorative as in your example.

Comment: No, it is not an expression in English.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard anything quite like that in English, but I like it. Informal greetings that come to my mind which approximate the tone and meaning of your phrase stem from "Here is", as in

- Here's Johnny!
- Here she is, the woman of the hour.
- Here comes trouble!
- Here's the high school brat.